# ¿Como puedo tomar los valores de un array y copiarlos en otro pero sumandole 1 a cada elemento?

Tags: javascript

Deberia de poder copiar un array en otro y poder sumarle todos sus elementos 1 a cada elemento

let array = [1,2,3,4,5,7];
let array2 = array;

```
function arrayANumero(array){
    var num = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        // Concatenamos cada uno de los digitos en una cadena
        num += array[i];
    }
  
    return (num);

}

console.log(array2)
```

Este es el codigo pero no me funciona para lo que necesito hacer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simplemente usa map, pasándole como función lo que quieres hacer con cada elemento. En este caso, sumarle 1.

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,7]
let array2 = array.map(element => element + 1)
console.log(array2)
```

Si lo necesitas con un `for` puedes intentar:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,7]
let array2 = [];
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  array2.push(array[i] + 1)
console.log(array2)
```

Usando `forEach`:

```js
 let array = [1,2,3,4,5,7]
 let array2 = [];
 array.forEach(element => array2.push(element + 1)) 
 console.log(array2)
```

Usando `reduce`:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,7]
let array2 = array.reduce((a,el) => {
   a.push(el + 1)
   return a},[]) 
 console.log(array2)
```

Usando un ciclo `while`:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,7]
let array2 = []

let i = 0
while(i < array.length){
  array2.push(array[i] + 1)
  i++
}
 
console.log(array2)
```

Usando recursividad:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,7]

function addOne(array, i = 0) {
  arr = [...array];
  if(i < array.length){
     arr[i]++;
     return addOne(arr, i + 1)
  }
  return arr;  
}

console.log(addOne(array))
```

Comment: También podrías agregar en la respuesta cómo se hace con un `forEach`.